# array length check does not seem to work on IOS/chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays

I want to check an array if it is an array or if it got any length. This is my code.

```
if(!$.isArray(bookedDates) || !bookedDates.length)
```

It works on the computer. But on the Iphone, Chrome/Safari this check is skipped. Does any body know why and how this can be fixed?

I also tried this

```
//bookedDates = [] looks like this. Its Empty

     var test = bookedDates.some(function(e) {

        return e.length === 0 ;
 });
if(test)//false
```

Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var test = function(array) {
  return array instanceof Array && array.length > 0;
};
console.log(test('hello')); // false, not an array
console.log(test([])); // false, is empty
console.log(test([1, 2])); // true
```

This will only return if the variable is an array and has a length of more than 0.

Comment: It works on the computer but not the Iphone. All other JavaScript work fine on the phone. Should checking of arrays work on the Iphone? or is there a special way of declaring a check for the iphone?

Answer (score 0):

I hade missed to format a date the correct way. thats why it didnt work